# Как добавить в TreeView стиль ScrollBar?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, wpf-стили

Как добавить в TreeView стиль ScrollBar, в виде такой ссылки на стиль (а не в виде ресурсов):

```
Style="{DynamicResource TreeViewStyleMyForScroll}
```

У меня в TreeView добавлены ресурсы:

```xml
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,0,1,0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="LightBlue" Margin="2"></Rectangle>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Track Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="True">
                  <Track.Thumb>
                       <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbStyle}">
                       </Thumb>
                  </Track.Thumb>
            </Track>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: А что в вашем `TreeViewStyleMyForScroll`? Почему вы думаете, что стиль из ресурсов сработает? Он упоминается в `TreeViewStyleMyForScroll`?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" в стиле. Тогда он будет применяться ко всем скролбарам внутри контрола.